# Implement Gmail Like "No connection" Alert at the bottom of screen

Tags: android, user-interface, gmail

Below is the Gmail No Connection alert. How would I go about achieveing this in my app?

Note: this is a question regarding the UI implementation, and not determining whether there is a connection. [image]

EDIT::

Is the bottom notification an anctivity themed as a dialog and placed at the bottom or is it some sort of AlertDialog?

Comment: This is a pretty general question...

Comment: I have given an edit...I am aware of it vagueness...I want to achive an alertdialog (if at all its that) similar to the one shown above from Gmail App

Comment: This is a snackbar - https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html#

Answer (score 2):

maybe that example can help you https://github.com/DanielRasta/Material-Design-Alert-Box-

EDIT 2 :
Material Design have [Snackbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) class too

Edit 1 :

Well, the idea is to call dialog activity in front. So to do that :

1 - Create alertbox_activity.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#8A8A8A">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alertbox_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#8A8A8A"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2 - Create an activity called AlertBoxActivity.java and paste this code

```
public class AlertBoxActivity extends Activity {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================  
    private static final int EXIT_DELAY= 3500;
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MESSAGE_TEXT = "AlertBoxActivity::message_text";  
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_PARENT_WIDTH = "AlertBoxActivity::parent_width";
    private static final String ERROR_GEN = "Oops.. Something went wrong.";

    private Runnable Exit(){
        return new  Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        };
    }   

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from super class
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle pBundle) {
        super.onCreate(pBundle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.alertbox_activity);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        TextView textViewMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alertbox_message);    
        String strNotificationToShow = ERROR_GEN;
        int myParentWidth = getWindow().getAttributes().width;
        try {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras != null) {    
                strNotificationToShow = extras.get(KEY_BUNDLE_MESSAGE_TEXT).toString();
                myParentWidth = extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_PARENT_WIDTH);
            }
            else{
                myParentWidth = getWindow().getAttributes().width;
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            strNotificationToShow = ERROR_GEN;
            myParentWidth = getWindow().getAttributes().width;
        }       
        finally{
            textViewMessage.setText(strNotificationToShow);
        }

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
        params.width = myParentWidth;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

        new Handler().postDelayed(Exit(), EXIT_DELAY);
    }   
}
```

3 - Add these lines to your manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.package.AlertBoxActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALERT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

4 - Call it

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALERT");       
i.putExtra(AlertBoxActivity.KEY_BUNDLE_MESSAGE_TEXT, "YOUR ALERT GOES HERE!");      
i.putExtra(AlertBoxActivity.KEY_BUNDLE_PARENT_WIDTH, getWindow().getAttributes().width);        
startActivity(i);
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is how Google implement their dialog but here is my Go around. I created a class that will be styled as a dialog in the manifest. So when I need to show the alert I simply start the Intent and its diaplayed. In the Activity I have a PostDelayed Handler taht will wait for 3.5 seconds and end the activity to give a toast like animation (similar to Gmail :-) )

Find Code Below

```
static final int EXIT_DELAY= 3500;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_pesabox_alert);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();  
    params.x = 5;  
    params.height = 150;  
    params.width = 700;  
    params.y = 5;  
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    new Handler().postDelayed(Exit(), EXIT_DELAY);
}

private Runnable Exit(){
    return new  Runnable(){     

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    };

}
```

The Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        android:drawablePadding="25dp"
        android:text="@string/connection"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A really old post but if anyone else is looking for google like "Bottom Toast like Notification". Refer to [Snackbar Material Design](https://material.google.com/components/snackbars-toasts.html#). Its also available in the support library. How to use Snackbar with backward compatibility is pretty well explained in this [blog](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/).